# Is it possible to get the range for a certain cell using spreadsheets api?

Tags: python, excel, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently writing a python script to append to a google sheet.
The sheet example is as follows:

```
TSLA AAPL GOOGL
1    2    3
2    4    9
3    8    27
```

I would like to append the values 4,5,6 to TSLA so that it becomes

```
TSLA AAPL GOOGL
1    2    3
2    4    9
3    8    27
4
5
6
```

To do so I am currently trying to use:

```
preadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=id, 
                              range=range_, 
                              valueInputOption='RAW', 
                              insertDataOption='INSERT ROWS', 
                              body=[1,2,3])
```

However, I am confused as to how I should approach RANGE, because I can't just input A to represent the first column as I will also one day have a lot more than 26 columns representing other stock symbols.
Is there an sheet api command that would return the range?

ie:

```
#hypothetical command
spreadsheet().getColumnRangeofcell('TSLA')
```

return A?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of the headers like that :

```
headers = wks.get_row(1, include_tailing_empty=False)
```

Then you can find the index of the element `TSLA` in `headers`:

```
pos = headers.index("TSLA") + 1
```

If `pos=1`, then `TSLA` is in **column A**.

Optionally, you can get the column data with the header `TSLA` :

```
TSLA_column = wks.get_col(pos,include_tailing_empty=False)
```

And then you can get the length of this column :

```
size = len(first_column)
```